What would happen if electrons passed through a double-slit after already passing through a Stern-Gerlach device?
I have heard about placing Stern-Gerlach devices one after the other, to demonstrate how in quantum mechanics measured properties persist so long as you keep measuring in the same basis (in this case, the property in question is spin). But what if, instead of another Stern-Gerlach device, you placed a double-slit? Even if for some reason the experiment proves impractical, can we predict what would happen using quantum mechanics?

The double-slit has nothing to do with spin and the Stern-Gerlach apparatus only acts on spin, so why would it matter that the electrons passed through an SG device before going through the double slit?

@ACuriousMind I've learned with quantum physics never to assume on the basis of common sense.


But what if, instead of another Stern-Gerlach device, you placed a double-slit?

Ok, no problem.

Even if for some reason the experiment proves impractical, can we predict what would happen using quantum mechanics?

Yes.
As the commenters have stated, spin and spatial variables can be treated separately to a good approximation in this context.
The Stern Gerlach apparatus can separate out spin components, but  has no action on the spatial part of the wavefunction (in the usual pedagogical setup).
The double slit experiment involves two slits, which are separated in space. Because of this spatial separation of the slits, quantum mechanics predicts a probability density on a recording screen placed after the slits that oscillates in space. But, this experiment is insensitive to spin (in the usual pedagogical setup).
